# Testing In-App purchases on iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am having trouble querying product info from the app store via in-app purchasing.  I have followed [this guide](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/) closely, but have one lingering question.

When you add products to iTunes connect, is it required to "submit for review" before they are able to be queried when launching through Xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have submitted your Paid Applications Contract and filled out your banking information. Until you complete these, In App Purchases will fail.